# how to apply focus to the input and outer label?

Tags: input, label, focus, addition

Need to add focus to the input and outer label.
I am trying to add focus CSS to the input and outer label.
so how can I add the focus to input with the outer span label?
can we add input:focus + label is it possible to do this kind of CSS?
you can see my code in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5tqB.png) the image.